# Using a loop to concatenate array strings with a variable in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

```
$strYesterdays_Date_4yr_First = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).ToString("yyyyMMdd")

$Atemp_file_names = @("userrnlg.","cpauditd.","auditclinician.","useraudl.","auditlog.")

for ($i=0;$i -lt $Atemp_file_names.Length; $i++){
  $Atemp_file_names[$i] = "$Atemp_file_names[$i]$strYesterdays_Date_4yr_First"
  Write-host $Atemp_file_names[$i]
}
```

I'm trying to use for loop to concatenate each array element (string) with yesterday's date.  I must be missing something, as the elements are not being modified. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should have write `"$($Atemp_file_names[$i])$strYesterdays_Date_4yr_First"` to receive the same result as in your answer. Do you expect more help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$strYesterdays_Date_4yr_First = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).ToString("yyyyMMdd")

$Atemp_file_names = @("userrnlg.","cpauditd.","auditclinician.","useraudl.","auditlog.")

for ($i=0;$i -lt $Atemp_file_names.Length; $i++){
  $Atemp_file_names[$i] = $Atemp_file_names[$i] + $strYesterdays_Date_4yr_First
  Write-host $Atemp_file_names[$i]
}
```

I figured it out, but thought I'd already had tried it this way.  Now I'm going to try using a foreach loop and see if I can make that work!

Comment: this one-line give same result: `$Atemp_file_names | % { "$_$strYesterdays_Date_4yr_First" }`